# Desinstalar pacotes e todas as suas dependências de uma vez

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget

Existe alguma forma para eu desinstalar packages e todas as suas dependências em um único comando? Sem ter que ficar desinstalando um a um. Tipo:

> Não é possível desinstalar 'System.Net.Http.4.3.3' porque
>   'NETStandard.Library.1.6.1' depende dele

Como eu faço?

**Edit1**

Fiz isso e não consigo desinstalar

> Uninstall-Package NomeDoPacote –RemoveDependencies

Aí tentei desinstalar o pacote
**NETStandard.Library.1.6.1** e recebi a seguinte mensagem: Pacote **NETStandard.Library.1.6.1** não foi encontrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o comando:

```
Uninstall-Package NomeDoPacote –RemoveDependencies
```

Este comando é responsável por remover o pacote e suas dependências.
É possível utilizar o comando `-Force` no final para forçar a remoção.

**Fonte:** [marcusoft.net](http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/02/nuget-uninstall-remove-dependencies.html)

Comment: Editei e você postou ao mesmo tempo, porque no meu edit eu disse que fiz isso. Só não usei o force. Vou tentar com o -force. Valeu LP Gonçalves.

Comment: Faltou o -force. Com ele foi.

Comment: Foi não, continua lá a DLL. Pensei que tinha resolvido, fechei e abri a pasta reference e continua. Não deu erro e deu concluído, mas ainda está DLL.

Comment: A dll aparece ainda en Referencias do Projeto(Droid), mas o NuGet deu como removido e não estou tendo mais o problemas que vinha tendo. Bem, pra mim não importa

Comment: A aplicação funciona? Estranho essas referências não terem sido removidas.

Comment: Foram, pois o NuGet disse que foi removida com sucesso, mas em referencias ainda tem o Nome delas, talvez se eu reiniciar o VS ou o Projeto ele desaparece, mas tá funcionando meu Proj, então deixar quieto. É que eu instalei no Droid sem querer, pois era pra ser no PCL apenas, mas lá tá dando pau, não estou conseguindo e até abri uma thread pra isso.